# 500 year post-apocalyptic story where soldier awakes from cryogenic sleep

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I have been trying to find the name of the series and author of stories about a mixed cadre of scientists and spec-ops who awake from cryogenic sleep 500 years after the apocalypse. The world is a mix of tribal groups similar to native Americans and dark ages. It was really well written and the author received acclaim for his first novel. I believe it was published by Tor in the late 80's. I read 2 novels but I believe there was a third.

Comment: You may need to add some more details. Check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if you can jog your memory. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds a little like Marvin Kaye & Parke Godwin's [*Masters of Solitude,*](https://www.amazon.com/Masters-Solitude-Marvin-Parke-Godwin/dp/0553247263/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=) which involves a conflict between low-tech Native American/Pagans, iron-age Christians, and high-tech City people in a post-apocalypse America.

Comment: That's pretty much the plot behind the early-80s tabletop RPG _The Morrow Project._  I don't remember any, but maybe some novels were written in that setting?

Answer (score 4):

I've read this recently.  It's *The Moondark Saga*, by Donald E. McQuinn, a triple trilogy (as far as I can find), which began appearing in about 1989-1990 time frame (Amazon doesn't give original copyright dates on the book's purchase page, only the date it went up on Amazon, but they have reviews dated from 1990).

Set five centuries (roughly) after the world has consumed itself in toxins, radiation, and overpopulation.  A small group of survivors wake from cryosleep in a malfunctioning vault and set about trying to survive in a world deeply changed from their own; meanwhile, a young man who is the subject of prophecy begins carving out an empire in a land readers will recognize as the Pacific Northwest.